# using regular expression how to find words that doesn't start with vowel

Tags: regex

using regular expressionThe set of all strings that consist of three or four lower-case letters, where the first character cannot be a vowel, and both ends of the string must be adjacent to space characters.

Comment: show the input string and the expected output

Answer (score 1):

## Description

```regex
(?<=\s)(?=[^aeiouy])[a-z]{3,4}(?=\s)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

This regular expression will do the following:

- Finds substrings that are 3 or 4 letters long
- Requires all the characters in the substring to be lower case letters
- Requires the first letter of the substring to not be a vowel `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`, or `y`
- Requires the substring to adjacent to space characters, but does not include the space character in the actual match

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/yJ2vR8/1

**Sample text**

> using regular expression The set of all strings that consist of three or four lower-case letters, where the first character cannot be a vowel, and both ends of the string must be adjacent to space characters.

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH 1
0.  [29-32] `set`

MATCH 2
0.  [48-52] `that`

MATCH 3
0.  [73-77] `four`

MATCH 4
0.  [104-107]   `the`

MATCH 5
0.  [147-151]   `both`

MATCH 6
0.  [160-163]   `the`

MATCH 7
0.  [171-175]   `must`
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^aeiouy]                any character except: 'a', 'e', 'i',
                             'o', 'u', 'y'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z]{3,4}               any character of: 'a' to 'z' (between 3
                           and 4 times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```